# Apache Tomcat executing a Java class

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets

I've coded some algorithms in Java and I need to include those algorithms in my web application.

I'm using Apache Tomcat and what I need to do is that when, for example, I click on the start button on my web page a Java class should be executed. I think this done by using servlets, am I right? If so, do you know where I can find some literature about it? I've searching in internet but it's a little bit confusing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right. You'd want to write a servlet that handles request to an URI.
Here's some introduction:

- http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/BasicJava1/servlet.html

Tomcat comes with some samples, you might look at the source code as a start, they should be in the webapps/sample directory.
The Tomcat documentation is also a good start.

- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc

Answer (score 0):

I would check out this [introduction to servlets](http://www.webdevelopersjournal.com/articles/intro_to_servlets.html)

A servlet receives an HTTP request (e.g. a request for a page etc.). It will process that request via the methods `doGet()` or `doPost()`, and return an HTTP response. That response will contain your results (most likely an HTML page, although that's not mandatory).

I would (in order)

1. get a static 'hello world' page going
2. get a static page returning some data from your libraries
3. get a dynamic page returning some data from your libraries using data from the HTTP request

Integrating your library will be trivial, since a servlet is simply a Java class that can instantiate/call on any other Java class.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to learn how to use Java in a web server.  I would recommend using JSP just to start with as it allows you to create web pages that call Java code easily.

There are many JSP tutorials on the net - I believe this one is suitable: http://www.jsptut.com/